# Equivalente en C# Class<T> de java

Tags: java, c#, genéricos

En Java, puedo declarar un genérico `T` y que un método reciba como argumento la clase a la que pertenece el genérico. Por ejemplo:

```
protected static <T> T hacerAccion (Class<T> respuesta) {
    //implementación...
}
```

¿Cuál sería el código equivalente en C# para este método, principalmente para el argumento `Class<T> respuesta`?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que quieres crear un método genérico en Java poniendo como ejemplo el de C#?

Comment: Al contrario crear un metodo generico en c# , la funcion que puse esta en Java

Comment: No hay un equivalente preciso para el `Class<T>`. Vale la pena que expliques, de forma más concreta, tal vez por medio de un ejemplo más completo, lo que estás tratando de hacer para poder sugerirte una alternativa aceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Para definir un método genérico en c# sería:

```
protected static T hacerAccion <T>(Class<T> respuesta) { //implementación... }
```

Obviamente la clase `Class` tendrías que definirla.

Comment: Creo que no entendistes la pregunta, porque `Class` en Java es una clase especial, no una clase cualquiera que puedas definir tu mismo. En realidad, equivale a `Type`. Lo único es que C# no tiene un `Type<T>` que sería el equivalente a `Class<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Mira, por lo que entiendo deseas alguna forma de obtener lo que te brinda java, este es un ejemplo muy abierto que tal vez te pueda servir. Hay muchos caminos para ello, este es uno de ellos.

```
public X metodoquedevuelve<X>(X valor)
{
    Type x = typeof(X); 
    if (Valor si es algún tipo) { } 
    return (X)someObject; 
}
```

Comment: Pero recibir un `T` en vez de un `Class<T>` son 2 cosas muy distintas. Si OP usa `Class<T>` en vez de simplemente `T`, me imagino que debe haber una buena razón para ello e implica que no debe tener acceso a una instancia de `T` al efectuar la llamada.

Answer (score 0):

Tomando este código en Java:

```
protected static <T> T hacerAccion (Class<T> respuesta) {
    //implementación...
}
```

Podría ser posible llamarlo de esta forma:

```
Integer i = hacerAccion(Integer.class);
```

Si lo que quieres es eso, lo que debes hacer en C# es lo siguiente:

```
protected static T hacerAccion<T> () {
    //implementación...
}
```

---

Tal vez quieres `Class<T>` para hacer verificaciones. En ese caso lo que quieres es `typeof(T)`:

```
protected static T hacerAccion<T> () {
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
    {
        // ...
    }
    //implementación...
}
```

A diferencia de Java, en C# puedes saber el tipo de datos en tiempo de ejecución sin necesidad de pasar un objeto que lo representa. Si aun así quieres un objeto que represente un tipo, sería `System.Type`, sin embargo no hay `System.Type<T>`, utiliza `typeof(T)` (que devuelve `System.Type`) en su lugar. Gracias esto C# no necesita `Class<T>` y no lo tiene.